# console.log shows the data but php echo does not

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

index.php

```
<body>
<script>
var h = $(window).height();
alert (h); // works fine - result is 580
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'pass.php',
    data: {h : h},
    success:(function(data){
        console.log(data);  // works fine - 580
    })
});
</script>

<?php
include ("pass.php");
echo $h;  // doesn't work. there is no echo of 580
echo "323"; // this works as a test
?>
```

pass.php

```
$h = $_POST['h'];
echo $h;
```

So, why I cannot get `580` as a result of `echo $h;` in `index.php`?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood how AJAX works. Have you followed any tutorials?

Comment: When `pass.php` contains `$_POST['h'] = 580;` it worked fine for me as a test `$_POST['h'] = 580; $h = $_POST['h'];
echo $h;`. So, you're doing something wrong, somewhere. Consult Quentin's answer.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, because in console I see `580` as a result.

Answer (score 3):

You are making **two** HTTP requests.

The first request is a GET request for `index.php`. That script `include`s `pass.php` which reads from `$_POST`. However, this time around, `$_POST` is not populated because it is a GET request. `$h` therefore does not get a value.

The second request is a POST request (from JavaScript) for `pass.php`. This time `$_POST` is populated.

Ajax does not retroactively change what the server previously sent to the browser for an earlier request. If you want to change what the user is seeing in response to Ajax, then you need to change the DOM using JavaScript (inside your success function).

Comment: Quentin, I don't want to change the DOM. I just need the `580` as a php variable, for another php calculation.

Comment: @bonaca — As you have already noticed, you have it available to you in the second request (the response of which you are `console.log`ing).

Comment: Quentin, but how can I get this value inside php code, as a php variable ?

Comment: @bonaca — It inside the PHP code as a PHP variable… for the second request. You can't have it from the first request because you haven't asked the browser for it until you respond to that request.

Comment: Quentin, excuse me, I don't fully understand what you're saying, but I will try. Anyway, thanks a lot for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about this. First of all, PHP founds following PHP code:

```
<?php
include ("pass.php"); // Okay, is an include in here, let's include the file
echo $h;
echo "323";
?>
```

After including:

```
<?php
$h = $_POST['h']; // Produces E_NOTICE because no index 'h' found
echo $h; // null
echo $h; // null
echo "323"; // 323
?>
```

So the result is `323`.
There is no POST data given in PHP code, so `$_POST["h"]` is null and gives no echo. Your ajax call sends POST data and because of it will be printed in PHP.

Comment: Why is result of `$_POST ["h"]` = null ?

Comment: @bonaca: `$_POST["h"]` is null because the first request is a GET request and gives PHP no POST data. GET request is a regular request which happends i.e. when clicking a link. POST request happens i.e. when submitting a form with `method="post"`.

Comment: So, how to get this `580` as a php variable ?

Comment: @bonace: Do not include pass.php and use echo in PHP at all. When user loads the page, print `$(window).height` value in the page.

Comment: user..., I need that value as a php variable, for another calculation inside php code.

Comment: @bonaca: Then use your original code. You have the PHP echos in `data` parameter given for function `success`.

Comment: user..., I need that value as a php variable, not as a console.log value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57604/discussion-between-user3725053-and-bonaca).

Answer (score -3):

```
data: {h : h}
```

Isn't this posting 580 : 580? Try

```
data: {"h" : h}
```

Comment: No, it isn't. The identifier on the left hand side of a `:` in an object literal is a property name not a variable name.